# Replace repeating substring pattern from string with regex

Tags: php, regex, string

I have the following string:

`"Canal Capital(Canal Capital) Felipe Cano - Recursos Humanos - fcano@sample.com - (Canal Capital) Andres Zapata - Tecnologías de la Información - zapatacano@sample.com - 3212032851(Canal Capital) Miguel Cabo - Canal Capital - cabop@gsample.com  - 457 83 00 Ext. 5227 301 734 07 56"`

I want to be able to remove a repeating pattern inside the string, so if the pattern is `(Canal Capital)`, I should end up with:

`"Canal Capital Felipe Cano - Recursos Humanos - fcano@sample.com - Andres Zapata - Tecnologías de la Información - zapatacano@sample.com - 3212032851 Miguel Cabo - Canal Capital - cabop@gsample.com   - 457 83 00 Ext. 5227 301 734 07 56"`

So far I've tried this (It works if the pattern repeats itself only once):

```
$cadena = preg_replace("/\(.*\)/", "", $cadena);
```

But I get just the first `"Canal Capital"` part. Can I achieve my goal with regex ? Maybe there's a better way to accomplish this that I don't know about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost close, you are just missing the `?` quantifier which makes the greedy matcher, non-greedy (lazy).

Try like this:

```
(\(.*?\))
```

which results:

> Canal Capital Felipe Cano - Recursos Humanos - fcano@sample.com - 
>   Andres Zapata - Tecnologías de la Información - zapatacano@sample.com
>   - 3212032851 Miguel Cabo - Canal Capital - cabop@gsample.com - 457 83 00 Ext. 5227 301 734 07 56

#### [Demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ckh)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern as

```
/(?<=[\w-\s\S])(\(.*?\))(?=[\w\s\S])/
```

- `(?<=[\w-\s\S])` Positive Lookbehind - `[\w-\s\S]` match a single character present in the list below
- `\(` matches the character `(` literally
- `.*?` matches any character `(except newline)`
- `\)` matches the character `)` literally
- `(?=[\w\s\S])` Positive Lookahead - `[\w\s\S]` match a single character present in the list below

So the code looks like as

```
$res = preg_replace('/(?<=[\w-\s\S])(\(.*?\))(?=[\w\s\S])/', '', 'Canal Capital(Canal Capital) Felipe Cano - Recursos Humanos - fcano@sample.com - (Canal Capital) Andres Zapata - Tecnologías de la Información - zapatacano@sample.com - 3212032851(Canal Capital) Miguel Cabo - Canal Capital - cabop@gsample.com - 457 83 00 Ext. 5227 301 734 07 56');
echo $res;
```

Or you can simply use this as

```
/(\(.*?\))/
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/418573)

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/sY3qI2/3)